# Windows XP search for files which have specfic name length

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-explorer, windows-search

I want to look for all `.txt` files in a folder, which their filename starts with `r` and is 4 character length or lower (<=4)

What's the query? (in Windows XP)

Comment: I'm guessing that powershell is not allowed since it is homework?

Answer (score 0):

`r???.txt` will work.  The question marks represent each character so it will match all txt files starting with `r` with up to 4 characters.

OR

PowerShell 
`get-childitem c:\ -r r*.txt |? {$.GetType().Name -match "File" } |? {$.basename.length -le 5} | %{$_.name}`